# Error: Invalid key length and Error: Invalid IV length using AES-256-CBC algorithm

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, encryption

I have 2 functions to encrypt and decrypt with AES-256-CBC algorithm:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto";

export const encrypt = (text: string, key: string, iv: string) => {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    let result = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "hex");
    result += cipher.final("hex");

    return result;
};

export const decrypt = (text: string, key: string, iv: string) => {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
    let result = decipher.update(text, "hex", "utf8");
    result += decipher.final("utf8");

    return result;
};
```

The problem is with key and IV. I had to generate IV and key like this:

```js
crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex') // IV
crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') // Key
```

I was trying to change length like this, but had 2 errors:

```js
crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') // IV
crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex') // Key
```

`Error: Invalid key length` and `Error: Invalid IV length`

But I have found that key has to have 32 bytes, not 16. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrectly hex-encoding your key and IV. Drop `toString('hex')` from both, these arguments must not be hex-encoded.

The correct length of the key and IV is 32 and 16 bytes respectively. By hex-encoding the strings, you're producing strings twice as long as is required, where each single byte goes from a value between 0 and 255 to a two character hex representation between between `00` and `ff`.

For example, the byte array `[255, 255, 255]` becomes the character array `['f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f']`.

Comment: But what if I need it in `.env`?

Comment: Then you can store them as hex, but you must *decode* them before passing them to `createCipheriv`, *not* encode them.